# condition display value from a select box

Tags: laravel

Hello Everyone I try to display a specific value in a form , from a select box . For exemple if i select "Arbitre Central" i would like to display 65 in the input text field to get the value in my controller . someone now how to achieve this ? 
thanks a lot in advance .

by the way this technic works for me with radio button but not with select box option !

here is my form with the main idea to want i'm looking for but of course it doesn't work :

```
<td>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="fonction" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
            <option name="choiceBareme" value="optionArbitreCentral">Arbitre Central</option>
            <option name="choiceBareme" value="optionJugeDeTouche">Juge de Touche</option>
            <option name="choiceBareme" value="optionDelegue">Délégué</option>
            <option name="choiceBareme" value="optionArbitreVideo">Arbitre Vidéo</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <div class="conditional" data-cond-option="choiceBareme" data-cond-value="optionArbitreCentral">
        0
    </div>

    <div class="conditional" data-cond-option="choiceBareme" data-cond-value="optionJugeDeTouche">
        1
    </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add new attribute in option for `special_val` which you want to reflect in input text on change

```
<select name="fonction" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
        <option name="choiceBareme" value="optionArbitreCentral" special_val="12">Arbitre Central</option>
        <option name="choiceBareme" value="optionJugeDeTouche"  special_val="912">Juge de Touche</option>
        <option name="choiceBareme" value="optionDelegue"  special_val="192">Délégué</option>
        <option name="choiceBareme" value="optionArbitreVideo"  special_val="62">Arbitre Vidéo</option>
</select>
<input type="text" value="" id="input_text" name="special_val">
```

and onchange call jQuery function

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js">
</script><script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.select2').on('change', function(){
        $("#input_text").val($('.select2 option:selected').attr('special_val'));
    });
});
</script>
```

check here : http://jsfiddle.net/0o368npa/

Comment: thanks for your reply it's exactly what i'm looking for ! do you have the cdn script for jquery to make it work on my app ? because actually the input display nothing

Comment: If you find my reply useful please accept the answer or up-vote the answer. and [jquery cdn](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js)

Comment: i will up vote but to make this work i need to include the cdn code of jquery right ? something like this ?  : <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        $('.select2').on('change', function(){
            $("#input_text").val($('.select2 option:selected').attr('special_val'));
        });
    </script>

Comment: thanks for the answer ! it doesn't work when i change the values in the select box ! where the problem is ? i put the script just before @endsection

Comment: still not but i will try to search why my javascript don't work ! but your code seems to work well

Comment: check your console it's will show you your javascript error.

Comment: Excellent jsfiddle in example.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var obj={optionArbitreCentral:65,optionJugeDeTouche:55,optionDelegue:46,optionArbitreVideo:68};
function displayVal(){
var val=document.getElementById('mySelect').value;
document.getElementById('myInput').value=obj[val];
}
</script>
<select id="mySelect" onchange="displayVal()" name="fonction" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
            <option name="choiceBareme" value="optionArbitreCentral">Arbitre Central</option>
            <option name="choiceBareme" value="optionJugeDeTouche">Juge de Touche</option>
            <option name="choiceBareme" value="optionDelegue">Délégué</option>
            <option name="choiceBareme" value="optionArbitreVideo">Arbitre Vidéo</option>
        </select>
   
<input id="myInput"/>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply ! i'm not a pro with javascript , i need to put var obj ... before @endsection on my page ? i need a java script cdn link to run this ?

Comment: you dont need any cdn link. do you have a javascript file (made by you) where you type in all your javascript functions? you just need to declare obj there

Comment: I just updated my answer above. If you dont have a js file you can just include the code above your select tag like in my answer above. This is done using pure javascript . You dont need to include a jquery cdn just for this.